# How to support the screen size for Landscape and Portrait in android studio

Tags: android, android-manifest, landscape, android-orientation

If portrait mode screen Size is good and while i'm changing into  Landscape mode screen size is different. I want to use both XML layout should be same screen size.

Comment: Use this library for responsive layout "implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'"

Comment: You must create different layouts for different screen sizes and aspect ratios. Refer to this link to learn how https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for problems/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.